# Highlight php lint error in emacs when saving php files

Tags: php, vim, emacs

After a while with vim, I am trying again to use emacs to edit PHP files.

I have a great feature in vim that run php lint every time I save a file, and that highlight errors in the margin.

Although I find how to call php lint in emacs using a shortcut key or when saving the file, I can't see where the errors are. There is just a message telling there is error, but not the line and neither highlighting the error.

Comment: [You didn't really try, did you?](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5859)

Comment: Sorry, I did not wanted to start a troll. Maybe I used the wrong library, it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the "flycheck" https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck
It is easy to setup and is able to highlights the errors on the fly.

Comment: Thank you. This is very useful, more than the previous answer.